# Make Spring java object request parameter required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-request-parameters

I have the following controller code

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUsers(Filter filter) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findUsers(filter));
}
```

Filter.java:

```
public class Filter {
    private Integer page;

    private Integer size;

    private String sort;

    ... lots of other parameters
}
```

The request parameters are written as a Java object to avoid adding lots of parameters to controller. However, all of the parameters are made optional by Spring. What I want is to have some parameters like `page` and `size` required, but others like `sort` optional. If I had them as controller parameters, I could use `@RequestParam(required = true/false)`. Is it possible to do something similar in Java class?

Comment: You can use kotlin and default parameters :) (It's a joke, not a really suggestion; but you can do this if you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the javax.validation API to specify some constraints on the fields of a class.
In your case you could use `@NotNull` and  `@NotEmpty` according to your requirements and the field types such as :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
...

public class Filter {

    @NotNull
    private Integer page;

    @NotEmpty
    private Integer size;

    private String sort;

    ... lots of other parameters
}
```

Then specify the `@Valid` annotation for the parameter you want to validate :

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
...
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getUsers(@Valid Filter filter) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findUsers(filter));
}
```

If the filter parameter doesn't respect the constraints, a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown that you can leave or catch to map it to a specific client 4XX error by using a Spring exception handler such as `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked: instead of `ConstraintViolationException ` there is a `org.springframework.validation.BindException` with a long nasty error message

Comment: You are welcome. You could paste the whole stacktrace in pastebin or  any website that allows that.

Comment: Add a "BindingResult bindingResult" after "@Valid Filter filter" so that spring has a way to tell you about the binding errors